# Pyspark: Adding row/column with single value of row counts

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rowcount, pyspark-schema

I have a pyspark dataframe that I'd like to get the row count for. Once I get the row count, I'd like to add it to the top left corner of the data frame, as shown below.

I've tried creating the row first and doing a union on the empty row and the dataframe, but the empty row gets overwritten. I've tried adding it as a literal in a column, but having trouble nulling the remainder of the column as well as the row. Any advice?

dataframe:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | col13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | string | timest | ... | int |

for a few rows.

desired output:

| row_count | col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | col13 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| numofrows |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | string | string | timest | ... | int |

So the row count would sit where an otherwise empty row and empty column meet.

Comment: ...but why? There isn't a single legitimate reason I can think of for wanting to do this...

Comment: what have you tried ? what is blocking you ?

Comment: I don't want to associate the row count with any of the other rows or columns. I want it to be standalone because I need to know how much I will need to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cnt = df.count()

columns_list = df.columns

df = df.withColumn("row_count", F.lit(None).cast("int"))
schema = df.schema

cnt_line = spark.createDataFrame([[None for x in columns_list] + [cnt]], schema=schema)

df.unionAll(cnt_line).show()
```